# htaccess enable browser caching only subdomain sites

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, caching

I have added browser caching in root `.htaccess` file, site working on multiple domains/subdomain like: `www.domain.com`, `mt.domain.com`, `rt.domain.com` and same code is using for all sites.. I have used `Codeigniter` framework

Now `caching` enable on all domain/subdomains, is it possible I can add specific domain/subdomains for caching

`.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    ########### TODO: deploying on subdir must rewrite this
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    Options -Indexes

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<FilesMatch "\\.(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>
```

thanks for help

Comment: Do you have access to the `httpd.conf`, more specifically your `VirtualHost` or the only option you have is the `.htaccess`? What is the version of your apache, 2.2+ or 2.4+?

Comment: i am able to access `httpd.conf` and apache is using version `2.2`

Comment: thanks for your response, i have created single virtual host `<VirtualHost *:80>` wildcard sub domains, because sub domain sites are not fixed, these publish/publish from site manager.. i want to apply caching on all sub domains sites and skip site manager (domain.com) from caching, but issue is main site and sub domains site code same.. can we use another `.htaccess` for sub domains **(*.domains.com)**,any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually possible with Apache 2.2, using environment variables. Unfortunately, it does not work with `mod_expires` (which you are using). We will be using `mod_headers` instead, which is not much different.

It looks a bit complicated, but this is due to the fact that we cannot logically combine (AND/OR) environment variables.

```
# Sets an env. var. if the subdomain matches, and initializes the other env. var.
SetEnvIfNoCase HOST ^subdomain\.example\.com$ do_cache=1 is_static_file=0

# changes the value of other env. var. if extension matches (here: PNG or GIF)
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .*\.(png|gif)$ is_static_file=1

# resets the first env. var. to 0 if the type didn't match
SetEnvIf is_static_file 0 do_cache=0

# now you can set arbitrary headers based on whether both conditions were met.
# (we're using nonsense "X-Success" headers here, for testing)
Header set X-Success "yes" env=do_cache
Header set X-Success "no" env=!do_cache
```

When you're ready to go live, replace the `X-Success` header lines with something like this:

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public" env=do_cache
```

This will activate the caching of your static files if they are called via the subdomain.

You can add as many `Headers` or other directives of this type as you wish. You must only make sure that the directive accepts the `env=do_cache` appendix (`Header` does, `ExpiresByType` doesn't).

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will try it.. how we will set `content-type` in `Header set..` because i want to instant expire content-type's (`text/html, application/json / text/json`)

Comment: Simply go by the extension. For static files it shouldn't be a problem. The only situation where this doesn't work are dynamic (PHP) files that write an own header. But they should also be able to control their own caching.